# MessagingException: Missing start boundary when sending mail with attachment

Tags: apache-camel, jakarta-mail, tomcat8

I am facing a problem, which has been reported here multiple times, but no solution helped me so far.

The route is a rather simple one. It wait's for an email with a specific subjects, creates a PDF from the parameters in the mail and mail this PDF back to the sender.

When I start the route as a Junit test case within Eclipse it works like a charm, but running it in the Tomcat on the Linux server it crashes with "javax.mail.MessagingException: Missing start boundary" when it tries to **send** the email with the PDF attachment.

*) Local Test Environment: 
Tomcat 8.0.5, Windows 7, Java 1.8.0_20, Camel 2.14.0

*) Server environment:
Tomcat 8.0.12, Ubuntu Server 14.0.1. LTS, Java 1.8.0_20, Camel 2.14.0

*) What have I tried already:
- Using newer version of mail.jar (by upgrading to the current Camel version) 
- Putting mail.jar, activation.jar into Tomcat lib
- Setting the various  mail.mime.multipart.XXX properties
All with different versions and combinations => no success.

Below the code of the route, the processor and the stack trace. Actually nothing spectacular in this route...

Any ideas???

The route:

```
from("imap://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?" +
        "host=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&" +
        "password=XXXXXXXXXX&" +
        "delete=true&" +                    
        "consumer.delay=12000&" +           
"searchTerm.subjectOrBody=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&" + 
        "searchTerm.unseen=true"        
    )
.routeId(ROUTE_ID)
.process(attachmentProcessor)

.setHeader("to", simple("${in.header.from}")) 
.setHeader("from", simple("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"))
.setHeader("subject", simple("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"))
.setBody(simple("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"))
.to("smtp://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
.log(mailMessage);
;
```

Part of the processor:

```
pdfUtil.generateLabels(tempDirPath, year, sequenceNumberStart, numberOfPages);
  exchange.getIn().addAttachment(fileName, new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(tempDirPath)));
```

The dreaded exception... :-(

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Missing start boundary
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.parsebm(MimeMultipart.java:882)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.parse(MimeMultipart.java:503)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:417)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1354)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1021)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:419)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1354)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2107)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2075)
        at org.apache.camel.component.mail.DefaultJavaMailSender.send(DefaultJavaMailSender.java:118)
        at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailProducer.process(MailProducer.java:56)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:143)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:307)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:138)
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
        at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.processExchange(MailConsumer.java:287)
        at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.processBatch(MailConsumer.java:213)
        at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.poll(MailConsumer.java:119)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem. The issue was caused by the inbound imap headers set on the In message on the exchange (boundary, mime type etc) which would confuse the SMTP server when you try to send the mail.

In the `attachmentProcessor` use the `Out` message instead of the `in` for the resulting body. This creates a new message which drops all the headers etc from the IMAP from component

eg:

```
       .process(new Processor() {   
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.getOut().setBody("here's the resulting message");
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the solution! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

- See [Missing start boundary Exception when sending messages with an attachment file in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408553/missing-start-boundary-exception-when-sending-messages-with-an-attachment-file-i). The solution suggests to check the classpath.
- See [Missing start boundary Exception when reading messages with an attachment file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043792/missing-start-boundary-exception-when-reading-messages-with-an-attachment-file?rq=1). The solution suggests to set property `mail.mime.multipart.ignoreexistingboundaryparameter`:

  ```
  System.setProperty("mail.mime.multipart.ignoreexistingboundaryparameter", "true");
  ```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Peter, thank you for your fast reply. Those two solutions (and many others) I have already tried. Unfortunately without success...