# getting Missing Start Boundary in javax.mail.multipart

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to read the emails using java mail API.

and when I tries to get count from multipart like this:

```
multipart.getCount()
```

I am getting the below exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Missing start boundary

    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.parsebm(MimeMultipart.java:872)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.parse(MimeMultipart.java:493)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.getCount(MimeMultipart.java:240)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the code as well ?

Comment: Guess the email is not a multipart document.

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4604855/5969092

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing start boundary Exception when reading messages with an attachment file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043792/missing-start-boundary-exception-when-reading-messages-with-an-attachment-file)

Comment: The error suggests that the email you're trying to read is corrupted, or at least not following the RFC requirements. Without a [mre] we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue can be resolved with the two properties that **MimeMultipart** holds...
I was also having the same issue and I resolved it with:

```
System.setProperty("mail.mime.multipart.ignoreexistingboundaryparameter", "true");
System.setProperty("mail.mime.multipart.allowempty", "true");
```

When you'll read the `MimeMulutiPart.java`, you'll find 5 properties:

```
 1. mail.mime.multipart.ignoremissingendboundary(def. true)
 2. mail.mime.multipart.ignoremissingboundaryparameter(def. true)
 3. mail.mime.multipart.ignoreexistingboundaryparameter(def. false)
 4. mail.mime.multipart.allowempty(def. false)
 5. mail.mime.multipart.bmparse(def. true)
```

and when I tried setting the remaining false to true. it worked for me.

Comment: Note that these properties are all workarounds for incorrectly encoded messages.  Whenever possible you should get the sending program fixed to encode the message properly.